# How to transfer music to iOS 9.1?

Tags: 14.04, rhythmbox, iphone, clementine, ios

Ubuntu version is 14.04. I'm tryin to transfer music with Clementine/Rhytmbox. Transfer looks like complete, files are on device and i can play them from ubuntu. Problem is that the phone can't see the music. Have any suggestions, how that can be fixed?

upd. Also tried VirtualBox with Windows 10 installed & iTunes. Song menu [has no option to transfer music](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bk8z.png).

Comment: "Problem is that the phone can't see the music" I would ask this on a apple related forum like http://apple.stackexchange.com/ What you state here tells me that on the  Ubuntu side there is nothing wrong ;)

Comment: Apple in its infinite wisdom has decided that any iOS device needs to have music added in a special way in order for it to show up. You need iTunes or some other special way to do it, but since this is off-topic, I'm going to leave it up to the people over at [apple.se] to tell you how.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command in terminal after connecting your phone to your PC.

```
sudo ideviceinfo -q com.apple.mobile.iTunes -k DBVersion
```

If it turns out DBVersion>4, you are out of luck. Any device with DBVersion>4 can not synchronize Music/Video with libimobiledevice library. It'll show up like the transfer is done, It will occupy your phone memory, but won't show up in your music app AKA Apple Music